# Missing Foursquare Category Icons

Tags: foursquare

I would like to get the Foursqaure category icons without the gray background.

However, it seems like many icons are missing. They are available if you want to construct the icons with the gray background. But once you are trying to get the icon without the gray background they are not available.

For example:
Gray icon for Breakfast is available:
https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/breakfast_bg_32.png

But without it, it is not:
https://foursquare.com/img/categories/food/breakfast_32.png

Is there a different URL I need use to construct to get all these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this url:

https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/breakfast_32.png

If you go to this page, it looks blank, but there is an image there (white icon on white background). View the page source and you will see that the icon is on the page. The icon should be in the upper left corner, you can right click on it, download it, and then view it in another app.

Comment: No, this is the icon with the gray background. That is the link that I know that is working. But according to the Foursqaure API (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/category) you can get a different type of icon. And that is the icon that is missing for many categories. You can see an example of that icon for the ice cream category: https://foursquare.com/img/categories/food/icecream_32.png

Comment: The icon that I linked to above has no gray at all in it. In fact, you can't even see it if you click the link because it's a white image on a white background. Reading the docs that you linked to is confusing, it seems to imply just adding "bg" will give you the background, but they show two different paths ("categories" and "categories_v2"). Note that that path I'm using is different than the two shown in your question.

Comment: Great! I didn't notice you didn't use the 'bg' url! Now, I need to color those icons.